# Criar um programa em C que leia um numero inteiro e determine a soma dos seus divisores

Tags: c, c++

Estou aprendendo C e estou com díficuldade em resolver esse exercício de estudo sobre ponteiros. É pedido para que o programa seja respondido em 2 funções (uma com a matemática e a outra com os printfs), justamente para fazer o uso dos ponteiros.

O código que eu tentei desenvolver, porém não consigo entender o porquê funcionou é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>

///Construa um programa emC que leia umnúmero inteiro não
///negativo e determine a soma dos seus divisores. A soma dever ser
///efetuada através de uma função somadiv e o resultado impresso no
///programa principal. O protótipo da função é:void somadiv(int x, int *y);
void somadiv(int *numero, int *soma)
{
    int divisor;

    for(divisor=1; divisor<0; divisor++)
    {
        if ((*numero)%divisor == 0) /// a divisão nn tem resto.
        {
            *soma = *soma + divisor;
            printf("\n\t valores do if: %i\n",*numero);
            printf("\n \t\tTeste com o soma:%i\n", soma);
        }
    }

}


int main()
{
    int numero;
    int numconta;
    int soma;

    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%i",&numero);

    numconta = numero;
    somadiv(&numero, soma);

    printf("\nO valor escrito e: %i\n",numconta);
    printf("\n A soma dos valores e: %i\n",numero);
}
```

Desde já eu agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Fala Canarin, bem vindo ao site. Do jeito que está, achei difícil entender qual a sua dúvida exatamente. Você disse que quer "entender o porquê funcionou", mas pelo que entendi, esse código não está funcionando. Foi um erro de digitação? Seria legal também explicar exatamente qual é a dúvida, de forma mais específica. Só perguntando porque funciona ou não fica difícil saber qual parte explicar. Olhando o código, algumas partes não parecem fazer muito sentido também. Se puder editar sua pergunta pra adicionar esses pontos, ajudaria bastante a obter uma resposta.

Comment: `for(divisor=1; divisor<0; divisor++)` esse comando nunca vai ser executado, se divisor começa em "1" e a condição é "menor que zero (<0)" então nunca vai entrar ai, comece olhando isso

Comment: A função que declarou não é a que descreveu no comentário e está invertendo onde é um ponteiro e onde é um endereço. Se acostume a mostrar esses valores na tela enquanto está testando seu programa. Vai ter surpresas.

Comment: E você mesmo escreveu que o resultado deveria ser impresso no programa principal. Mas deixou 2 `printf()` na função...

Answer (score 0):

> O código que eu tentei desenvolver, porém não consigo entender o porquê funcionou

Também não entendo como possa ter funcionado. Do modo como escreveu deve simplesmente retornar sem fazer nada.

```
    int divisor;

    for(divisor=1; divisor<0; divisor++)
```

conforme dito nos comentários não vai entrar nesse loop nunca e na falta de um `return` explícito vai retornar porque chega ao fim do código da função.

De seu código:

```
//programa principal. O protótipo da função é:void somadiv(int x, int *y);
void somadiv(int *numero, int *soma)
```

Você acabou de dizer no comentário que o primeiro parâmetro é um `int` mas declara ao invés disso um `int*`. Está errado o comentário ou a declaração?

A função como escrita

```
void somadiv(int *numero, int *soma)
{
    int divisor;   for(divisor=1; divisor<0; divisor++)
    {
        if ((*numero)%divisor == 0) /// a divisão nn tem resto.
        {
            *soma = *soma + divisor;
            printf("\n\t valores do if: %i\n",*numero);
            printf("\n \t\tTeste com o soma:%i\n", soma);
        }
    }

}
```

ao entrar no loop e usando `%` para encontrar um divisor pode não ser a melhor opção: Se `b` divide `x` então existe `a` de modo de `x = a * b`, e assim você encontra os divisores aos pares, certo? Então usar módulo é um provável desperdício. E claro que à medida em que aumenta um fator o outro diminui, de modo que não deve ir além da raiz quadrada do número.

Por outro lado todo número é divisível por `1` e por ele mesmo.

```
 printf("\n \t\tTeste com o soma:%i\n", soma);
```

Esse `printf()` está errado. `soma` é `int*` e deve escrever `*soma`

```
    scanf("%i",&numero);

    numconta = numero;
    somadiv(&numero, soma);
```

Isso também está errado: deve passar `numero` para a função, o valor lido, e não o endereço dele. E o endereço de `soma`, porque é onde vai retornar o valor somado pela função. Devia usar

```
    scanf("%i",&numero);
    numconta = numero;
    somadiv(numero, &soma);
```

E teste sempre o retorno de `scanf()`: não há sentido em chamar a função se não ler nada.

### Considere esse exemplo:

```
void somadiv(int numero, int* soma)
{  // se ab = x a e b sao divisores de x
    // todo numero e divisivel por 1 e por si mesmo
    *soma = 1; // sempre
    if (numero < 2) return;
    *soma += numero;  // o minimo se > 1
    if (numero == 2) return;
    for (int a = 2;; a += 1)
    {
        int b = numero / a;
        if (b * a == numero)
        {
            if (a == b)
            {
                *soma += a; // nao pode ter outros
                return; // depois desse
            }
            *soma += a + b;
        }
        if ((a * a) >= numero) return; // fim da linha
    }
    return;
}
```

Trata os casos especiais: `0` `1` e `2`... E daí pra diante encontra os divisores aos pares e para na hora certa.

#### um programa de teste

```
int main(void)
{
    int teste[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 17, 32, 25, 9, 8, 1024};
    int N       = sizeof(teste) / sizeof(teste[0]);
    for (int i = 0, soma = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        somadiv(teste[i], &soma);
        printf(
            "A soma dos divisores de %d: %d\n\n", teste[i],
            soma);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Esse programa simplesmente chama a função para os valores na tabela `teste`. Eis a saída

```
A soma dos divisores de 0: 1

A soma dos divisores de 1: 1

A soma dos divisores de 2: 3

A soma dos divisores de 3: 4

A soma dos divisores de 4: 7

A soma dos divisores de 17: 18

A soma dos divisores de 32: 63

A soma dos divisores de 25: 31

A soma dos divisores de 9: 13

A soma dos divisores de 8: 15

A soma dos divisores de 1024: 2047
```

#### uma versão mais verbosa

Com uns `printf()` de teste fica mais clara a lógica:

```
void somadiv(int numero, int* soma)
{  // se ab = x a e b sao divisores de x
    // todo numero e divisivel por 1 e por si mesmo
    printf(
        "\nsomadiv(%d)\n    %d e %d\n", numero, 1, numero);
    *soma = 1;
    if (numero < 2) return;
    *soma += numero;  // o minimo se > 1
    if (numero == 2) return;
    for (int a = 2;; a += 1)
    {
        int b = numero / a;
        if (b * a == numero)
        {
            if (a == b)
            {
                *soma += a;
                printf("    divisor: %d\n", b);
                return;
            }
            *soma += a + b;
            printf("    divisores: %d e %d\n", a, b);
        }
        if ((a * a) >= numero) return;
    }
    return;
}
```

#### A saída para essa versão

```
somadiv(0)
    1 e 0
A soma dos divisores de 0: 1


somadiv(1)
    1 e 1
A soma dos divisores de 1: 1


somadiv(2)
    1 e 2
A soma dos divisores de 2: 3


somadiv(3)
    1 e 3
A soma dos divisores de 3: 4


somadiv(4)
    1 e 4
    divisor: 2
A soma dos divisores de 4: 7


somadiv(17)
    1 e 17
A soma dos divisores de 17: 18


somadiv(32)
    1 e 32
    divisores: 2 e 16
    divisores: 4 e 8
A soma dos divisores de 32: 63


somadiv(25)
    1 e 25
    divisor: 5
A soma dos divisores de 25: 31


somadiv(9)
    1 e 9
    divisor: 3
A soma dos divisores de 9: 13


somadiv(8)
    1 e 8
    divisores: 2 e 4
A soma dos divisores de 8: 15


somadiv(1024)
    1 e 1024
    divisores: 2 e 512
    divisores: 4 e 256
    divisores: 8 e 128
    divisores: 16 e 64
    divisor: 32
A soma dos divisores de 1024: 2047
```

Comment: :) E dessa vez levou mais de 1 hora para uma resposta minha ser marcada como inútil! Mas é bom pra eu lembrar que preciso melhorar!